# Typescript: automatic type conversion between interfaces where one interface is more stringent than the other

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

If I have an object that fits two interfaces, with one less stringent than the other, can typescript automatically convert between them? or do I have to provide an explicit cast or use generics?

for example:

```js
interface Foo {
  a: string
}

interface Bar {
  a: any
}

x: Foo = {
  a: 'hello'
}

const useBar(bar: Bar) {
  ...
}

useBar(x)  // is this valid?
```

context: I have a part of my codebase that I want to split off as its own library. This 'library' uses its own types, but some of the exported functions for this library use those types as parameter and return types. I don't want to have to export those types, if I can avoid it, because it would result in unnecessary imports in other places.

Comment: [Why not just try it?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyycAXMgM5hSgDmBAvgQaJLIigEJxQ4FGnEQATwZN8CdCErIAHmQxYAvL0LEyAcgAWEADY7060fgISpYZAFdyELj2UAKAEbcytgJTJFAPhVEjBKxtuexkPZAB6cORgcmQwTRjkADc4HWAAEwB+IA) The code in the question looks OK - if you have another example that's failing for you feel free to edit it into the question

Comment: thanks, didnt know about the ts playground until today. Lucky 10000 i guess (https://xkcd.com/1053/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works fine -- tested it successfully on the [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyycAXMgM5hSgDmBAvgQaJLIigEJxQ4FGnEQATwZN8CdCErIAHmQxYAvL0LEyAcgAWEADY7060fgISpYZAFdyELj2UAKAEbcytgJTJFAPhVFT5dB0IADp9GiduNyMCKxtuexkPZAB6ZORgcmQwTQzkADc4HWAAEwB%20IA). Also learned about ts playground today